# Python/Plotly: How to print y-trend values from LOWESS line?

Tags: python, regression, plotly, extract

Here is what my snippet of LOWESS Smoothing looks like when I use Plotly lib: 
[image: LOWESS Smoothing line]

Now, I know that using Plotly it provides me the y-trend values if I hover over the line:
[image]

**Problem:** I do not know how to print out these trend values.

I am aware there is a function `px.get_trendline_results(forecast_fig)` but it prints out nothing for me...

[image: use of known function]

Help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today these values are not available but they could be in a future version! The reason nothing comes out of `get_trendline_result` is that LOWESS has no underlying model, it’s just a kind of average.

Under the hood Plotly Express uses the `statsmodels` library to generate LOWESS curves so you can probably run the same analysis outside of PX for now.

Here is the code PX uses: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/blob/3ca829c73bd4841666c8b810f5e8457514eb3c99/packages/python/plotly/plotly/express/_core.py#L232

If you want to query the actual values out of the figure, and you have nothing mapping to `color` or `symbol` then you can do something like:

```py
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="total_bill", y="tip", trendline="lowess")
print(fig.data[1].y)
```

but if you have `color` set, then the actual trace index in `fig.data[ <index> ]` will vary so this is pretty brittle.

Comment: Edited to give the line number in the link! Sorry :)

Comment: Hi @nicolaskruchten! Hmmm, so if I understand you right even though these trend values shows when hovering over the line, it is impossible to extract them in a 'print' format for each x observation? Now if Plotly Express uses the statsmodels lib, is there other libs you could suggest or within the same lib on how to print out those values; I strongly doubt that there is no way to print these trend values outside of PX - hopefully you can point me in a right direction :)

Comment: Also, regarding your first sentence... I am aware on how LOWESS is calculated and that it is indeed a moving average, however I am a bit confused on what you meant... Did you mean that these trends are impossible to extract specifically because of trendline='lowess' that I'm using, would the functionality be there to print those trend values if I used trendline='ols' ?

Comment: apologies for another question, but also very important to me... I found that when using px.scatter() there is NO argument to specify the bandwidth, which is very important when using LOWESS; do I not see it or it doesn't exist in PX?

Comment: Right now with PX you cannot specify the bandwidth, that's correct. It's on our roadmap to provide more control over the trendline options (i.e. setting the constant in OLS etc).

Comment: Re the other points: in OLS `statsmodels` actually returns a "model" object so PX stores it and you can retrieve it with `get_trendline_results` but LOWESS has no such object so we don't. The actual data values are stored in `fig.data[something].y` where `something` depends on how many colors you have so it can be pretty brittle to query them out.

Comment: (I've updated my answer to show how you can get this out using the brittle approach)

Comment: Thank you very much for explanations and for fig.data[something] breakdown! Regarding your last statement about 'brittle approach' - does it have to be? ...if I can just make a loop to go through all existing [something] and get printed all the values - trying it right now :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202909/discussion-between-dgomonov-and-nicolaskruchten).